# Font weight is not working in React Native expo app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fonts, expo, font-family

I am working on React Native Expo app for Web, IOS, Android. I have downloaded "Red Hat Display" font with all bold, medium, regular variants.
This is my code

```js
 import * as Font from 'expo-font';

 const useFonts = async () =>
  await Font.loadAsync({
    'RedHatDisplay-Black': require('../../assets/font/Red_Hat_Display/static/RedHatDisplay-Black.ttf'),
    'RedHatDisplay-Bold': require('../../assets/font/Red_Hat_Display/static/RedHatDisplay-Bold.ttf'),
    'RedHatDisplay-ExtraBold': require('../../assets/font/Red_Hat_Display/static/RedHatDisplay-ExtraBold.ttf'),
    'RedHatDisplay-Light': require('../../assets/font/Red_Hat_Display/static/RedHatDisplay-Light.ttf'),
    'RedHatDisplay-Medium': require('../../assets/font/Red_Hat_Display/static/RedHatDisplay-Medium.ttf'),
    'RedHatDisplay-Regular': require('../../assets/font/Red_Hat_Display/static/RedHatDisplay-Regular.ttf'),
    'RedHatDisplay-SemiBold': require('../../assets/font/Red_Hat_Display/static/RedHatDisplay-SemiBold.ttf')
  });

  export default useFonts;
```

This is how I am using :

```js
 <Text  style={{ fontFamily: 
          'RedHatDisplay-ExtraBold', 
          fontSize: 22, 
          fontWeight:'100',
          letterSpacing:0.03,
          color: '#020215'
           }}>
```

But Font is loaded and is applied but fontWeight has no impact. Does not matter which font I use, Regualar ,Medium, Bold ( with or without  fontWeight property).They all rendered at 400 and do not change in any environment ( Web,Android).

Any idea what is missing , or I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: Anyone ....any idea?

Comment: import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';

export default function App() {
  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    'Inter-Black': require('./assets/fonts/Inter-Black.otf'),
  });

  // ...
}
Then, you can use the font on the Text component by using fontFamily style prop.

<Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Inter-Black', fontSize: 30 }}>Inter Black</Text>